Grafana & Prometheus how to group values by label after regex applied?
I've been trying to create a query that displays the average latency of each path on my application, while using Promql on Grafana:
sum by(path) (rate(http_server_latency_milliseconds_sum[$__rate_interval])) / sum by(path) (rate(http_server_latency_milliseconds_count[$__rate_interval]))

However, "path" on some values have duplicates like "/users/" and "/users", but they are the same path.
I would like to combine them into one path "/users/" and then display on Grafana.
So my logic would be:
for all labels, check if it ends with '/', if doesn't, add a '/' and sum with already existing one, from then put rate() and sum()
How do I do that?
Does it requires some transformation or value mapping?

Since you are dealing with division, you'll need to handle label grouping inside promql, not Grafana. For that you can use label_replace around each rate two times.

Hm, even one label_replace per each part should be enough: sum by(new_path) (label_replace(rate(http_server_latency_milliseconds_sum[$__rate_interval]),'new_path','$1/','path','(.*?)/?') / ....
